# How do I apply boldface to multiple Khmer words in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, xetex, fontspec, ucharclasses

I create documents that include both Latin and Khmer (Cambodian) characters. To type in Unicode, I use the `fontspec` package and typeset using `XeLaTeX`. To move between the two scripts I use the package `ucharclasses`.

My problem is this: when I put two or more `Khmer` words into a tabular environment, any text style that ought to target the entire string instead alters only the first word in the string. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times}
    \usepackage[Khmer]{ucharclasses}
    \setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\fontspec[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{Khmer Mondulkiri}}
    \setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        ខុស​ហើយ & \quad not bolded\\
        \textbf{នេះ ខុស ដែ} & \quad \textbf{three bolded words}\\
        \bf នេះ ខុស ដែ & \quad \bf three bolded words\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Once typeset, it looks like this:

[image: result of above MWE]

Notice that neither `\boldface` nor `\bf` works for the Khmer – except the first word.

(To get the MWE example to work, you'll need a decent Khmer font: many pre-installed stock Khmer fonts don't have boldface at all. I've used Khmer Mondulkiri, an open font available from SIL.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `\normalfont` for the transition, and as obviously the space is a transition places this resets the series. Use only `\rmfamily`. It is also better to define a dedicated font family for khmer instead of loading it with fontspec::

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\khmerfamily[Scale=0.8,Script=Khmer]{Khmer Mondulkiri}
    \usepackage[Khmer]{ucharclasses}
    \setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\khmerfamily}
    \setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
        ខុស​ហើយ & \quad not bolded\\
        \textbf{នេះ ខុស ដែ} & \quad \textbf{three bolded words}\\
        \bfseries នេះ ខុស ដែ & \quad \bfseries three bolded words\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike. Worked perfectly. Honestly, I don't understand what `\normalfont` is (I copied the code from somewhere!), or why a transition would be different with `\normalfont` rather than `\rmfamily`. It seems as though a space is a transition either way.

Comment: `\normalfont` is defined as `\usefont\encodingdefault                          \familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault` so it resets *everything* to "normal" and so e.g. instead of the bold series your get the normal mdseries. `\rmfamily` only changes the family.